# White Screen with Ionic Webview Iframe

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 and webview on my App project, All is working fine on iOS but the problem is when I press the next button it will come to white screen on Android Webview Iframe.

Steps to recreate:

1. Here my Ionic info

   ## Ionic:

   - Ionic CLI          : 5.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   - Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   - @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

   ## Cordova:

   - Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   - Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   - Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 14 other plugins)

   ## Utility:

   - cordova-res : 0.6.0
   - native-run  : 0.2.5 (update available: 0.2.8)

   ## System:

   - Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   - ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   - NodeJS            : v8.16.0
   - npm               : 6.4.1
   - OS                : macOS Mojave
   - Xcode             : Xcode 10.3 Build version 10G8
2. Here my Cordova plugins list

   - cordova-plugin-app-name 1.0.4 "App Namer"
   - cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
   - cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
   - cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.6 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
   - cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
   - cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
   - cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
   - cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
   - cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
   - cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
   - cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
   - cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
   - cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.0 "Toast"
   - cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
   - cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
   - cordova-unique-device-id 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"
   - es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
3. Here my Code

## Home.ts

```
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesProvider } from '../../providers/services/services';

let win: any = window;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    url: string = "";

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, public Services: ServicesProvider) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        if(this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            this.url = this.Services.getStorageDirectory();
            this.url = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(this.url) + "/index.html";
        }
        })
    }
}
```

## home.html

```
<iframe [src]="url | safe" name="trustResourceURL" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="this.style.visibility='visible';"></iframe>
```

## safe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safe',
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

I hope some one can help me figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Why don't you use  `inAppBrowser` for external website.

Comment: Thanks Najam, It is still problem when I used inAppBrowser. on Android Emulator is working fine. But on real android is still not working.

Comment: what errors are you getting. please share